# "I saw your lesson request, but when I saw *it* it was late"

Tags: idioms, pronouns

If I want to say:

> I saw your lesson request, but when I
>   saw **it** it was late.

Is it correct to use the first **it**? I know that in this sentence the first **it** function as a pronoun, and the second as an idiom. If this sentence looks awkward, please give me a suggestion to improve it.

Comment: I think both *it*s are pronouns... though I may be mistaken.

Comment: The first *it* is a normal [pronoun with an antecedent](http://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/pronante.html).  The second is an [expletive pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_pronoun). Yes, both are pronouns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is correct; however, I would place a comma between *it* and *it* or (better) just replace "when I saw it" to say:

> "I saw your lesson request, but by then it was late."

Comment: This sounds better indeed... +1

Answer (score 9):

Yea, you need to add a comma between it and it.

OR (better). You could use

> By the time I saw your lesson request, it was late.

-EDIT- 
Looks like someone beat me to it. 
His answer is just as good, if not better. But I can't upvote it, since I'm new here.